# using IF statement to get all fields depending on the LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

so I have this query

```
SELECT IF(c2.nid IS NULL, c.*, c2.*) FROM table1 c LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c.cid = c2.pid WHERE c.pid = 0 AND c.nid = 674662;
```

Notice that both c and c2 are referring to table1....basically, I want it so that if a left join entry exists, it will return the row in the left joined c2 whereas if it doesn't exists, it'll return the entries in c1...

However, executing this query will yield mysql syntax error..how do I go about accomplishing what im trying to accomplish (preferably in a single IF statement)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @luksch answer, you can do this by using `IF()` or `COALESCE()` function on every column you need.

The only way that I can think of is with a `UNION` and splitting the two cases:

```
SELECT c2.*
FROM table1 c 
  INNER JOIN table1 c2 ON c.cid = c2.pid 
WHERE c.pid = 0 AND c.nid = 674662

UNION ALL

SELECT c.*
FROM table1 c 
  LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c.cid = c2.pid 
WHERE c.pid = 0 AND c.nid = 674662
  AND c2.pid IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fear you can't use the star pattern within `IF` statement. So you need to explicitly type it out like

```
SELECT IF(c2.nid IS NULL, c.cid, c2.cid), 
       IF(c2.nid IS NULL, c.pid, c2.pid), ... 
FROM table1 c LEFT JOIN table1 c2 ON c.cid = c2.pid 
WHERE c.pid = 0 AND c.nid = 674662;
```